# Aspirated voiceless plosives after consonants at the end of words

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics, consonants

It is my understanding that:

- Voiceless stops are aspirated at the beginning of a word, and at the
  beginning of a stressed syllable.
- Voiceless stops are unaspirated at
  the beginning of an unstressed syllable.
- They’re also unaspirated in any other position, like at the end of a syllable or the end of a
  word.
- If a syllable is stressed, a voiceless stop is
  unaspirated if it follows [s].

Also, in this question: [Are English consonant sounds [p], [t], [k] aspirated before another consonant?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122964/are-english-consonant-sounds-p-t-k-aspirated-before-another-consonant),
the matter of aspiration before consonants has been in discussed at length. However, I found in this book for ESL students: *Pronounce It Perfectly in English*, ISBN-13: 978-0764177491.

That:

- When a word ends in another consonant plus /p, k, t/, the /p, k, t/ sound must be aspirated, for example:
- /p/: lamp, harp, grasp, scalp, limp, sharp, wasp, help
- /k/: frank, ink, work, fork, ask, talk, walk, mosque
- /t/: act, lift, fault, apt, can't, text, last, borscht

Here's my question: is that a reliable rule? Are voiceless plosive sounds aspirated at the end of words when come after another consonant?

I'm asking about Standard American English in particular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That rule is not true, but is kinda close. A bit of linguistic expansion first.

In English, there are **three** *allophones* of each of /p/ /t/ and /k/, being:

- "aspirated" [p<sup>h</sup>]
- "unaspirated" [p]; and
- "unreleased" [p ̚ ].

"Unreleased" means the place of articulation isn't even opened, so it can only occur at the end of a syllable. The shape of the mouth at the end of the preceding vowel is enough to indicate which consonant it is. So in the case of [p ̚ ], at the end of the word "top", we can close the lips to form "p", then never release the lips so no air gets out.

With words that end [ vowel + /p, t, k/ ], the pronunciation of /p, t, k/ is in *free variation*, which means all three allophones are correct.

With words that end with [ consonant + /p, t, k/ ], the shape of the final plosive isn't present during the vowel sound, so we must pronounce it **either unaspirated or aspirated** for it to be heard, not unreleased.

Comment: You said that "With words that end [ vowel + /p, t, k/ ], the pronunciation of /p, t, k/ is in free variation, which means all three allophones are correct." Doesn't it break the "rule" of non-aspiration at the end of syllables/words? Also, do voiced plosives have the allophones: unaspirated and unreleased? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Darvid I'm not familiar with any "rule of non-aspiration at the end of syllables/words". Can you tell me more what you're talking about? It's natural to aspirate at the end of a syllable/word. Yes, the voiced plosives only have unaspirated and unreleased allophones.

Comment: thanks for answering. In [this article](https://www.linguisticsnetwork.com/aspiration-in-standard-american-english/) about Aspiration in Standard American English, I read that voiceless stops should "not [be] aspirated in word final position".
Also, in [a post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFPbLcUCraQ&t=0s) by a popular YT channel I found: "At the end of most words (and syllables) stop sounds are pronounced without a puff of air. For example, 'lap,' 'sheep,' 'update.'" They call it [the final stop rule](https://twitter.com/soundsamerican/status/951833920533823489)

Comment: @Darvid Aspirated is less common word-finally than unaspirated or unreleased, and when I do it on purpose it sounds like I'm a bit upset, but IMO it's an overstatement to say there's a *rule* against it. Linguistics isn't a hard science, and majority opinions do change. What I can say for sure is that 20 years ago, linguistics students like me learned that all three allophones are in free variation at the end of utterances.